# material table sort pagination and filter all three not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, metronic

I tried searched in Stack Overflow I am not getting correct solution for my problem.

I am not getting any error but my pagination, Sort & filter not working.

Here is my **HTML** code

```html
<div class="example-header">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table [dataSource]="MyDataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="EMPID">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>EMPID #</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let dashdata">{{dashdata.EMPID}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="plNumber">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Planned Number#</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let dashdata">{{dashdata.plNumber}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Fname">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>First Name</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let dashdata">{{dashdata.Fname}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Salary_Variance">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Salary Variance</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let dashdata">{{dashdata.Salary_Variance}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Skill">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Skill</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let dashdata">{{dashdata.Skill}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Certificates">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Certificates</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let dashdata">{{dashdata.Certificates}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Status</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let dashdata">{{dashdata.status}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastUpdate">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Last Updated</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let dashdata">{{dashdata.lastUpdate}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="Action">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let dashdata"  > 
                            <span *ngIf="dashdata.status === 'Data Load Pending'">
                                <mat-icon> email</mat-icon>
                            </span>
                            <span *ngIf="dashdata.status === 'pending'">
                                    <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                            </span>
                    </mat-cell>
            </ng-container> -->
    <mat-header-row class="table-header" *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row [ngClass]="{'is-red': row.status === 'Data Load Pending'}" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns">
    </mat-row>
  </mat-table>
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Here is my **Service** code

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { myDash } from '../../../../views/pages/my-dash-page/mydash'
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MydashService {
  // serviceUrl = '../../layout/server/database.json';
  private headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  // _baseUrl:string;

  private _baseUrl = '../../../../../assets/database.json'
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getUser(): Observable<myDash[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<myDash[]>(this._baseUrl);
  }

  // private generateHeaders = () => { 
  //   return {
  //     headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  //   }
  // }

}
```

Here is my updated  component code.

```js
      import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
      import { MatTableDataSource,MatPaginator,MatSort } from '@angular/material';
      import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
      import { myDash } from './mydash';
      import { MydashService } from '../../../core/_base/layout/services/mydash.service';
      @Component({
        selector: 'kt-my-dash-page',
        templateUrl: './my-dash-page.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./my-dash-page.component.scss']
      })
      export class MyDashPageComponent implements OnInit  {

        displayedColumns = ['EMPID', 'plNumber', 'Fname', 'Salary_Variance','Skills','Certificates','status','lastUpdate'];
        MyDataSource: MatTableDataSource<myDash>;

        @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
        @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

        constructor(public myDash: MydashService) {this.MyDataSource = new MatTableDataSource();}  

        ngAfterViewInit(): void {

          this.MyDataSource.sort = this.sort;  
        }
      ngOnInit(): void { 
      // this.MyDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.myDash.getUser()
          .subscribe((res)=> { 
            this.MyDataSource.data = res['studies'];
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.MyDataSource.sort = this.sort;
              this.MyDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
            });
              console.log(this.MyDataSource);

            },error => {
              console.log('There was an error while retrieving Posts !!!' + error); 
            }
          )
      }

      applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        this.MyDataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
      }

      }
```

with my above code I was able to get the value from json and I can able to populate inside the table but Sort, Pagination & filter this three not working though I gave correct coding based on the document but still not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide stackblitz? it will be much easier to find solution.

Comment: @Plochie actually I was not much familiar with stackblitz

Comment: Okey. Can you at least paste the response of `this.myDash.getUser()`?

Comment: @Plochie here is my stackblitz  but not ale to map service & interface
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwtj7c

Comment: @Plochie

export class MydashService {
  private headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });    
  private _baseUrl = '../../../../../assets/database.json'
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  getUser(): Observable<myDash[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<myDash[]>(this._baseUrl);   
  }
}

Comment: please provide `/database.json` in assets folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204501/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-plochie).

Comment: You should import modules in your `AppModule` not components. You imported `MatSortComponent` instead `MatSortModule`

Comment: @Elder I did still no use

Answer (score 0):

You've killed your dataSource with these lines, specifically the second line where you assign res['studies'] equal to this.MyDataSource your MyDataSource object is no longer a MatTableDataSource object:

```
this.MyDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
this.MyDataSource = res['studies'];
```

Remove these two lines and do something like this:

```
this.MyDataSource.data = res['studies']
```

Comment: thank you now pagination is working can you please help on sort and filter too...

Comment: can you please help on sorting and filter